# syntax error in mysql while using prepare statement in stored procedure with parameters

Tags: mysql

i have a table named salesperson in which fields like id,name,jobtitle are included. i want to select all records where job title matches using stored procedure and prepare statement.
Here is my code below.

```
delimiter $
create procedure pro9(a varchar(25))
declare job varchar(25);
set job = a;
begin
prepare st0 from 'select * from salesperson where jobtitle = job;';
execute st0;
deallocate prepare st0;
end$
delimiter ;
call pro9("salesman");
```

Comment: honestly avoid stored procedures. They are hard to debug and a straight query from your application code will work just as well. You can look at examples in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html). TIP you don't need prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below store procedure :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `salesdata`;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE SALESDATA (JOB_TITLE varchar(30))
BEGIN

    SELECT s.* 
      FROM salesperson s
     WHERE s.jobtitle = JOB_TITLE;

END //

DELIMITER ;

call SALESDATA("salesman");
```